# is it correct to refer to a plagiarism, like a book, as a plagiarized book?

Tags: word-usage

I stumbled upon a thread on Reddit saying that a certain game review was plagiarized. My initial thought was that someone stole some ideas from this review. However, it turned out that this very game review was a plagiarism.
But could it be that plagiarized can be used adjectively so something is plagiarized means something is a plagiarism? But then, if someone plagiarizes material A to publish material B, shouldn’t material A be called plagiarized?

Or maybe plagiarized is used wrongly here.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you do not adopt the practice of calling A *plagiarized* in the scenario above.  It is highly misleading and would be incorrectly interpreted by almost every listener.  Also, *plagiarism*, in common usage, is “the act of plagiarizing” I’ve never heard it used as “the concrete result of plagiarizing”  it sounds wrong tocmy ear.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and surely I will not use plagiarized that way. As for using plagiarism as a countable noun to denote an idea or story that has been plagiarized, it is strange to me too, but some dictionaries do include that entry, but more or less in a fixed collocation, like "this article is full of plagiarisms"

Answer (score 1):

A plagiarized article, depending on the context, could have both the meanings you mention.

If I plagiarize a book, then the book is plagiarized (*by* me).
The article which I subsequently write is plagiarized too (*from* the book).

[Your dictionary](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/plagiarized) gives the föllowing examples (the italics added by me):

> He violently attacked Politian (Poliziano), whose Miscellanea (a
>   collection of notes on classical authors) were declared by Merula to
>   be either *plagiarized from* his own writings or, when original, to be
>   entirely incorrect.
>
> In 1803 he produced El BarOn in its present form; originally written
>   (1791) as a zarzuela, it was shamelessly *plagiarized by* Andres de
>   Mendoza, but the recast, a far more brilliant work, still keeps the
>   stage.

But in both examples above, the participle functions as part of the verb phrase in a passive structure. Here is [a more recent usage](https://about.hindawi.com/blog/how-to-avoid-being-accused-of-plagiarism/) corresponding to your Reddit case with the participle used adjectivally (italics mine):

> 1. Understand how plagiarizers are caught
>
> Plagiarizers are now extremely likely to be caught. Publishing staff
>   are trained to spot plagiarism – and reviewers, editors and readers
>   (including those whose work has been plagiarized) may also spot
>   *plagiarized work*. If plagiarism is found in one article, this may lead
>   to thorough checks of all other articles by that author. But how is
>   plagiarism found?

[And this one](http://www.plagiarismchecker.com/plagiarism-vs-copyright.php) from a plagiarism detections site:

> Plagiarism
>
> Plagiarism is using someone else's work without giving proper credit.
>   Schools deal with plagiarism by giving the cheaters academic
>   consequences. Most teachers will give F grades for *plagiarized work*,
>   and some will do more. When I was a teaching assistant at Stanford
>   University, some students were suspended for copying answers during a
>   test.

When you submit plagiarized work in this sense, you are submitting your 'own work' and another's work at the same time. So it's easy enough to imagine how the two uses could have arisen.

Comment: I checked some dictionary websites and it seems very rarely is plagiarized used adjectively, but in Roget's A-Z Thesaurus and Oxford Thesaurus, this word is listed as a synonym of unoriginal and copied.

Comment: As a practical matter, before saying that one was plagiarized from the other, I would try to find out which was written first. If one is clearly much older, that would pretty much settle it. If I were not certain who copied from whom, I might point out that the text in one exactly or closely matched the text in the other. Wrongly saying that something was plagiarized could be libelous.